# SSRS Row Visibility on Text click rather than Plus Minus sign

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have my SSRS report working properly, row visibility displaying correctly etc. However I would like to display my row visibility by using text as the clickable object, rather than the [+] & [-] sign.

Is this a possibility within SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with a Parameter:

1. Create a HideRow Parameter, type Boolean, Hidden. Set the default of the HideRow Parameter to your desired Hidden value for the Row when the Report is first executed.
2. Set the row's Hidden value to `=Parameters!HideRow.Value`
3. On the properties of the textbox you want to to control the row visibility, set the Action to "Jump to Report". Set the Report name to your Report name. Set the HideRow parameter value to `=Not(Parameters!HideRow.Value)`

This hyperlink will reload the report with the opposite HideRow parameter value.

Comment: I had thought about this, but having to wait for a report to reload each time you want to expand a row is far too much of an overhead in comparison to using the [+] / [-] buttons, so just wouldn't be practical.

Comment: How up to date does the data need to be? If you have a regular job returning your data in an optimized table just for that report, it should load a lot faster. You could also set your SQL to initially aggregate the data, which is much faster than loading thousands of rows to SSRS and aggregating there, and then drill down based on the group column clicked. This way, your SQL is only retrieving data the user is requesting. Just some ideas. Good luck to you :)